# Python ggplot and ggplotly

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

Former R user, I used to combine extensively ggplot and plot_ly libraries via the ggplotly() function to display data.

Newly arrived in Python, I see that the ggplot library is available, but cant find anything on a simple combination with plotly for graphical reactive displays.

What I would look for is something like :

```
from ggplot import*
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'grid': np.arange(-4, 4),
                 'test_data': np.random.random_integers(0, 10,8)})
p2 = ggplot(a, aes(x = 'grid', y = 'test_data'))+geom_line()
p2
ggplotly(p2)
```

Where the last line would launch a classic plotly dynamic viewer with all the great functionalities of mouse graphical interactions, curves selections and so on...

Thanks for your help :),

Guillaume

Comment: You can create graphs which are stored as HTML files or use a Jupyter Notebook to get interactive graphs together with your code.

Answer (score 4):

This open [plotnine issue](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/262) describes a similar enhancement request.

Currently the mpl_to_plotly function seems to work sometimes (for some geoms?), but not consistently. The following code, seems to work ok.

```
from plotnine import *
from plotly.tools import mpl_to_plotly as ggplotly
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'grid': np.arange(-4, 4),
             'test_data': np.random.randint(0, 10,8)})
p2 = ggplot(a, aes(x = 'grid', y = 'test_data')) + geom_point()
ggplotly(p2.draw())
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need ggplotly in python if all you are seeking is an interactive interface.
ggplot (or at least plotnine, which is the implementation that I am using) uses matplotlib which is already interactive, unlike the R ggplot2 package that requires plotly on top.