# ggplotly like function for python

Tags: python, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, plotnine

In `R` there's a function (`ggplotly`), that converts `ggplot2` plots to `plotly` graphs. In `python` you have `plotnine` for using `ggplot`, but is there a similar converter like `ggplotly`?

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587634/python-ggplot-and-ggplotly), but is asking about the older (and I think deprecated) library for python, and thus I think my question is relevant.

Comment: https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/262